# MacOS - Fullscreen Windows Remote Desktop Keeps Sliding Out of View

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, macos-ventura

On MacBook Air M1 running Ventura 13.3.1, whenever I attempt to run a Microsoft Remote Desktop session in fullscreen, it opens in a separate "space" but immediately slides back to the main desktop, out of view. When I swipe back to it, it immediately slides back. When I swipe up to view the spaces bar, it shows up there, but when I select it, it again immediately slides back to the desktop.

I am able to work around this by using windowed and not full-size, but obviously not ideal.

Comment: Does it 'slide back' to anything specific, or just 'whatever you were last on'? Is it one session or all? Have you done a reboot since this started?

Comment: It slides back to the main desktop. There are no other "spaces" open or defined besides the desktop and the full screen remote session when it is running. It slides back for any remote session I have defined. Rebooted and have run all updates. It's been happening for a couple of months. But not sure when it started exactly. MRD is up to date and running 10.8.2.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did this myself, but the MS team have very good bug reporting in their beta versions - they *actually answer you* on occasion & fix things. [IKR, this doesn't ever really happen in real life]. I think it might be worth a shot at the current beta - which if nothing else will let you raise a bug report - https://install.appcenter.ms/orgs/rdmacios-k2vy/apps/microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac/distribution_groups/all-users-of-microsoft-remote-desktop-for-mac No guarantees in any of this of course, but they might just figure out if it's you or them at fault.

Comment: [You can have both release & beta at the same time, different colour icons & they don't fall over each other]

Comment: Thanks so much, I will report there also.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was somehow Full Keyboard Access under MacOS -> Settings -> Accessibility had been enabled. Disabling this fixed the problem.